# Чёрное окно WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

Тупо чёрное окно при запуске приложения, при том что VS XAML designer исправно его отображает, появилaсь проблема просто во время того как я оформлял `ScrollBar`. Ошибок тоже нет:

[image: чёрное окно]

В то же время в Visual Studio:
[image: окно в XAML designer]

Пробовал запускать код в другом проекте, результат тот же.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Alarm.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Alarm"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Alarm" MinHeight="200" Height="450" MinWidth="300" Width="600" Style="{DynamicResource WindowStyle}">
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackground" Color="#162633"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BoxContentBackground" Color="#274559"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Primary" Color="#416578"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryOver" Color="#4E7C99"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryPressed" Color="#30556E"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimarySelected" Color="#30556E"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarBackground" Color="#2E5169"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryForeground" Color="#E0E0E0"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AdditionaryForeground" Color="#9E9E9E"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryForeground" Color="#222222"/>

    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="7"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="15,5,5,15" Background="{DynamicResource Primary}" BorderThickness="0" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="0" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="0" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.RowSpan="3" CornerRadius="15,5,5,15" Background="{DynamicResource ScrollBarBackground}"/>
                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" IsDirectionReversed="True" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb Style="{DynamicResource ScrollBarThumb}"/>
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource WindowBackground}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ContentBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BoxContentBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5,5,3,3"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ContentBorderStyle2" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BoxContentBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="15,15,15,15"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ContentBorderStyle3" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BoxContentBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4,4,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="AlarmsListStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Primary}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5,5,3,3"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryOver}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryPressed}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PrimarySelected}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="DefaultButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Primary}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="17"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryOver}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryPressed}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="AlarmListTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="23"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Fantasy"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="AlarmListAdditionStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource AdditionaryForeground}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Visibility="Visible">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="145*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Margin="10,10,10,10" Padding="10,10,5,10" Style="{DynamicResource ContentBorderStyle}">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Height="800">
                <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" GroupName="Group" Style="{DynamicResource AlarmsListStyle}">
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource AlarmListTextStyle}">
                                    <Image />
                                    <Run Text="6:00"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="Example | Example" Style="{DynamicResource AlarmListAdditionStyle}"/>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </Border>
                </RadioButton>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Style="{DynamicResource ContentBorderStyle3}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button x:Name="editBtn" Content="Edit" Margin="10,10,2.5,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultButtonStyle}"/>
                <Button x:Name="selectBtn" Content="Select" Margin="2.5,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultButtonStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Button x:Name="deleteBtn" Content="Delete" Margin="10,10,2.5,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultButtonStyle}"/>
                <Button x:Name="createBtn" Content="New" Margin="2.5,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultButtonStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: В стилях `Window` попробуйте `OverridesDefaultStyle` установить в `false` или уберите совсем, он по умолчанию будет `false`

Comment: Действительно помогло, благодарю.